# http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, debian, debian-buster

Hi I have a linux server (debian 10 buster) w

after typing the command: `sudo apt-get update` for updating

there was en error shown :

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease                                                                                         
Get:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                              
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease [23.9 kB]                                                                                
Hit:7 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease                                       
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 1200:89c:6950:8000::17 80]
Get:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [246 kB]
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4E..
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4E.....
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
```

How i could solve that please?

Comment: " http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish" : Impish is Ubuntu 21.04 → i.e. the latest included Ubuntu version is 20.04 **focal** http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Besides that, why add an old incompatible Ubuntu PPA, when all `gearman-1.1.18` is available by default for Debian ? ...........  https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=gearman